# Can I convert relationships in MS Project from Start-to-Start to Finish-to-Start? Is there any equation for it?

Tags: ms-project, project-management-style

I have a MPP file with Start-to-Start relationship between tasks. But when I import to MPP in one project, I need to convert it to Finish-to-Start relationship because the system only supports finish-to-start relationships.

Comment: Though I've provided a technically correct answer, this seems like a silly request.  The existing schedule may include many SS+lag relationships.  Simply converting these to FS+lag relationships completely changes the logic of the schedule.  You should re-plan tasks and relationships from the beginning.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Condition here is, I have MPP with 400 tasks and some tasks have SS+<Number> relationships. But my web portal only have FS+<number> relationship settings. So how to convert SS to FS with some equation that works for all tasks

Answer (score 1):

1. Display all tasks. i.e. make sure filters are clear and outline shows all tasks.
2. Open the Find/Replace window from the Editing group on the Task Ribbon (Shortcut is Alt-E-E).
3. Find what: SS
4. Replace with: FS [or leave blank]
5. Look in field: Selected; "Predecessors"
6. Replace all.

Note: the resulting schedule may be radically different than the one you started with.  Save before you start.